# puppeteer hangs while generating large pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, puppeteer

I have a pdf generation API which takes JSON data, creates html page using ejs templates and generates PDF. For 45 page PDF it takes around 2 min. When I am trying with large amount of data that will result in 450+ pages it just hangs. Previously it used to throw `TimeoutError: waiting for Page.printToPDF failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded`. But I added `timeout: 0` option. Now it just hangs. There's no response. I tried looking for online solutions. No luck.

Here's the code.

```
ejs.renderFile(filePath, { data }, async (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        // error handler
    } else {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu"]
        })
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
        const fileStream = await page.pdf({
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            footerTemplate:
                '<div class="footer" style="font-size: 10px;color: #000; margin: 10px 
                auto;clear:both; position: relative;"><span class="pageNumber"></span> 
                </div>',
            margin: {top :30 ,bottom: 50},
        });
        await browser.close();
        res.send(fileStream)
    }
})
```

I added some console logs. It gets stuck on `page.pdf()`.

Comment: Hey Rajesh have you got the solution for the same !!! If you got the answer would you please solution with me because I am still facing the same in generating pdf

Comment: Hey. I still haven't found any solution for this. We had to change our implementation when using this. Instead of generating pdf from huge amount of data, we generate small PDFs and merge it.